# Pass an arbitrary sequence of tokens into a Rust macro

Tags: rust, macros

I'm using a declarative macro to generate an impl block on a type, and I need to add a `where` clause with constraints passed into the macro.  The only way I can think of to do this is by somehow passing in arbitrary strings of tokens.

Desired behavior:

```rust
macro_rules! make_me_an_impl {
    ($struct:ty, $trait:ty, $params: something, $where:something) => {
        impl<$params> $trait for $struct where $where {
            fn some_function_or_other(&self) {
                println!("hello!");
            }
        }
    }
}

make_me_an_impl!(MyStruct<T>, MyTrait, {T}, {T: MyOtherTrait});
```

Is this possible without resorting to procedural macros?

Also, if possible, I'd like to avoid using the `$(...)*` syntax in the solution since AFAIK those are one to a declarative macro and I'm already using it for something else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is the `tt` specifier (which means "token tree", in other words "anything"). And you can of course have multiple `*` patterns in the same macro:

```
macro_rules! make_me_an_impl {
    ($struct:ty, $trait:ty, {$($params:tt)*}, {$($where:tt)*}) => {
        impl<$($params)*> $trait for $struct where $($where)* {
            fn some_function_or_other(&self) {
                println!("hello!");
            }
        }
    }
}

make_me_an_impl!(MyStruct<T>, MyTrait, {T}, {T: MyOtherTrait});
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=ad29ded954bd3d5de7f0486c7c4ded34)